# WP8: Page Navigation Transition without white space

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-toolkit

I'm using toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition (SlideIn and SlideOut) for animate page navigation.

It works fast, but looks like like slow and buggy because:

- at first Page1 is hiding (SlideOut) and you can see white space;
- when Page1 is hided, the Page2 animation begins (SlideIn )...

I hate this white space blink.
How can I do page transitions (SlideIn and SlideOut) simultaneously? Now this animation plays successively...

*Look at the picture*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pydrO.png

**UPD:** At the worst How can I create this page navigation effect:
Page 2 Slides over Page 1. Like in default Store application when you press Search button in appbar.

*Navigate to Page2*: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/501264

*Go Back from Page2*: social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/501265

Comment: This is hard because i think that usually these animations animate old page, then load new page and then animate new page. This way you have this white space. To have it your way i think you have to reimplement the animation and preload the second page and animate both...

Comment: How can I preload second page? Maybe if default animation will be a little bit faster I can like it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be helpful [Left And Right Side Menus Similar To Facebook App](http://developer.nokia.com/blogs/community/add-side-menus-to-an-windows-phone-application-similar-to-the-facebook-app)

Comment: It's iOS-style. I want native solution :)
You can see needed effect in Store application when press Search button in Appbar... Search-page slide-up over main-page... Magical. How can i repeat this?